# What's the difference between 正しく, 正に, 正確に, 丁度, きちんと and ぴたり?

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, adverbs, i-adjectives, na-adjectives

Which ones are interchangeable?

Also, what's the difference between their adjective version: 正しい, 正確な, きちんとする, ぴたりする? I don't know if the last two are correct.

Please, add similar adverbs and adjectives in your answer.

Comment: It's something you're gonna learn by yourself as you learn and speak japanese more in the future. You can lookup a dictionary otherwise.